# Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified error using Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, invalidselectorexception

I'm trying to click on this element:

```
<td role="gridcell" class="mat-calendar-body-cell mat-calendar-body-active ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" data-mat-row="0" data-mat-col="1" aria-label="May 2, 2022" aria-selected="true" style="width: 14.2857%; padding-top: 7.14286%; padding-bottom: 7.14286%;"><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-content mat-focus-indicator mat-calendar-body-selected mat-calendar-body-today"> 2 </div><div class="mat-calendar-body-cell-preview"></div></td>
```

To do so, I'd like to select it via the element's aria-label (May 2, 2022). So I have a variable that contains the string "May 2, 2022" (the string is called theElement), and I plug it into a find_element function.

Why is this code snippet giving me the:

```
Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

error?

Code trials:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="[aria-label="+theElement+"]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the *`<td>`* element through the value of the *`aria-label`* attribute i.e. *May 2, 2022* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td[aria-label='May 2, 2022']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@aria-label='May 2, 2022']")
  ```